# Split polygon of two separate islands

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, splitting

Behold the photo:

[image]

I want to split the two islands into two separate polygons. The Cut tool does not work. Is there a way to split these polygons without having to redraw them?

ArcGIS 10.5.1

Comment: I don't know for only two polygons directly in editor mode. You can select them, use `Multipart to Singlepart` and after this, replace them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an edit session, select the polygon(s). On the editing/advanced editing toolbar, click the 'Explode Multipart Feature' button [image]. Save edits.